# Solr query to compare two derived fields

Tags: solr

I know that a range query can be performed to search for field values within a specific range, say field_1 > 2, with the syntax q=field_1:[2 TO *]. But, supposing I have two fields named field_1 and field_2 in my Solr collection, how would I query for field_1 > 2 * field_2? Would q=field_1:[product(2,field_2) TO *] work?

I’ve read the Apache Solr documentation but wasn’t able to find a section addressing this particular case.

Comment: Does `fq={!frange l=0 incl=false}sub(field_1,product(field_2,2))` do what you want? i.e. a function range query where any value above 0 would work, since `field_1 - field_2 * 2` would be negative when `field_2 * 2` is larger than `field_1`? `incl=false` should exclude the rows where they're identical.